# How to put required angular directive inside Html Helper?

Tags: c#, angularjs, forms

I have a form with some html helpers.

e.g.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {id = "FirstName"})<br>
```

im trying to use angular material, one thing in particular I want is to include the directive 'required'

e.g.

```
<input required name="clientName" ng-model="project.clientName">
```

Does anyone know where to put the 'required' directive inside my HTML helper? I've tried putting it just about everywhere and it always throws an error??

Comment: As I person who came from the .NET world, the sooner you migrate your templates to be HTML only rather than Razor when using AngularJS, the better off your will be.

Comment: I agree with @Chris Story, better use "regular" inputs with angular... the Razor here only complicate things

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ng_required="true"` which will evaluated as `ng-required="true"` directive & will add `required` attribute.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {id = "FirstName", ng_required="true"})<br>
```